# Get the latest completion state with out using join in sql

Tags: sql

i have data like this.

id   |  Completion status

1    |  incomplete

2    |  Enrolled

1) To get the max of id, i am using max() function.
2) To get last updated completion status (Note: last updated status is enrolled ) i can use inner join with id. But it causes some performance issue. without using join i want to get max id ( 2 ) and max completion status (enrolled)

Comment: Please show us your code, take a look at: **How to ask a good question.** http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: It's a bad idea to use an ID as a grade. What if you wanted to introduce another status 'almost done'? Would you give it the ID 1.5? Or Change table IDs here and in all referring tables? Add a grade column (or however you want to call it) that tells you the order of the statuses instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best solution is to re-write the application to `UPDATE` the latest data into into a different table, that way it's a really quick and simple `SELECT` to latest readings.